# Maven-src-plugin & Java 11 - unable to scan class files:

Tags: java, maven, sling, maven-compiler-plugin, maven-scr-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade my project setup to run on Java 11 & Sling 11. For this purpose I have been trying to upgrade my Maven compiler to 3.8.0 but this seems to be causing issues with the maven-scr-plugin; making it unable to scan a simple class containing only an enum.

The error I get when trying to build the Maven project is the following:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.26.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project foo-forms.core: {file location} : Unable to scan class files: {package.foo.class} (Class file format probably not supported by ASM ?): IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
```

And here is most of my POM file (sensitive info removed):

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Release Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Source Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Jar Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Enforcer Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[2.2.1,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <message>Project must be compiled with Java 6 or higher</message>
                                    <version>1.10.0</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven IntelliJ IDEA Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
                    <linkModules>true</linkModules>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Eclipse Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Maven Clean Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Apache Felix SCR Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.26.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>scr</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Private service properties for all services. -->
                                <properties>
                                    <service.vendor>bar</service.vendor>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.25</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Installer Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Surefire Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>
                            --illegal-access=permit
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Failsafe Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>
                            --illegal-access=permit
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Deploy Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Apache Sling Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <slingUrl>http://${sling.host}:${sling.port}/system/console</slingUrl>
                                <user>-</user>
                                <password>-</password>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Apache Felix Bundle Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.3</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Enforcer Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Dependency Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Build Helper Maven Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.2,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.5,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- D E P E N D E N C I E S -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.12</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
                <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
                <version>1.50.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Apache Sling Dependencies -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.commons.osgi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.osgi</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Servlet API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- JCR -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Taglibs -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
                <artifactId>cq-wcm-taglib</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
                <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.outreach.workflows</groupId>
                <artifactId>workflow-engine.core</artifactId>
                <version>[1.0.0,)</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.outreach</groupId>
                <artifactId>pojotools.core</artifactId>
                <version>[1.0,)</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.outreach.sql</groupId>
                <artifactId>datasource.core</artifactId>
                <version>[1.0,)</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.outreach</groupId>
                <artifactId>entities.core</artifactId>
                <version>[1.0,)</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.doctusoft</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-schema-java7</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>ui</module>
    <module>tests</module>
    <module>launcher</module>
  </modules>
```

I've been troubleshooting for a little bit and my understanding is that the scr-plugin simply doesn't support the newest maven-compiler as one was released several months prior to the other (see links below):

[maven-scr-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aq20.png)

[maven-compiler-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icdTE.png)

I was wondering if anyone had run into a similar issues and had figured out some workaround. Thank you!

Comment: use maven bundle plugin, and newer osgi r6 annotations. maven scr plugin has been in maintenance for years now

Answer (score 2):

By moving to Java 11 the class files you create will be compiled to Java 11 byte code. The `maven-scr-plugin` then has to scan this byte code to find the annotations that are applied to it. Unless you can find a version of the `maven-scr-plugin` that supports Java 11 byte code (I'm not aware of one) then you will need to find an alternative for creating your Declarative Services metadata.

One option would be to start using the `bnd-maven-plugin` or `maven-bundle-plugin` and the standard Declarative Services annotations instead of the Custom Felix annotations. Note that this would still involve updating those plugins to versions which can support Java 11. I believe that the `bnd-maven-plugin` version 4.1.0 should work properly with Java 11...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to migrate to bnd-maven-plugin which is sort of a superset of maven-bundle plugin. It has a better developer base and will be maintained for future java versions too.

AEM-acs-commons and latest maven archtype (23 at the time of this answer) too have ported to the bnd plugin.